# Closure Void -> Void

Tags: swift, swift2

Running the following in Xcode 7.2(7C68) Playground. OS X 10.10.5

Can you tell me why the following is not printing "Example"? It just prints "`()`"

As you can see in the comments it works in 7.1.

```
func printThis(xprint : Void -> Void) {
    xprint()
}

printThis({ print("Example") })
```

Comment: Well if anything it's going to print "Example". Typo?

Comment: It does print "Example" on my machine in playground.

Comment: As stated it works, look at the code here: http://swiftstub.com/948006802/

Comment: Thanks, it must be my Playground then...

Comment: @ChrisG. Could you edit and mention what version of Xcode you are using? The `swiftstub` site uses Xcode 7.1. I'm using Xcode 7.2 and the output is `"()"` (or maybe I'm not using the Playground properly, I rarely use it at all).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am using 7.2. I will update the question.

Comment: Works on my 7.2, on 10.0.5. What OSX version do you run onto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to differ between *output in the console* and the *value of an expression*. Also note that `Void` is just a typealias for the empty tuple, `()`. Functions with no return type returns, by default, the *value* of an empty tuple, `()`.

```
func printThis(xprint : Void -> Void) {
    xprint()
}

let a = printThis({ print("Example") })
/* the _value_ of this expression is ()
   the side effect of this expression is that "Example" is
   printed to the console output */
print(a) // prints '()'
```

The `()` *value* has nothing to do with your `()->()` closure, but with the fact that `printThis(..)` is a void function, in the sense that it implicitly returns value `()` of type `()` (empty tuple).

As an example, consider the following case with a side effect of printing *"Example"*  to the console, but with a integer *value* of 1.

```
func printThat(xprint : Void -> Void) -> Int {
    xprint()
    return 1
}

let b = printThat({ print("Example") }) // side effect: prints "Example"
print(b) // 1
```

What you see in the right side of your playground is the *value* of variables and expressions. Refer to the bottom to see console *output*.

---

Finally, regarding *"void"* functions, note that there is no difference between these two function signatures:

```
func myFunc(myVar: String)        // implicitly returns _value_ '()' of _type_ ()
func myFunc(myVar: String) -> ()
```

Curiously enough, you can have an optional empty tuple type, so the function below differs from the two above:

```
func myFunc(myVar: String) -> ()? {
    print(myVar)
    return nil
}

var c = myFunc("Hello") /* side effect: prints 'Hello'
                           value: nil
                           type of c: ()?              */
```

For details on the empty tuple `()` as type as well as value, see e.g.

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34561452/3

Comment: nice explanation! I have one more note to it. There is a good idea to mention what type has the closure. For an example `let what1: Void->Void = {}` or 
`let what2: Int->Int = { i in return i }` are both valid expressions with different types. So xprint has the type ()->() (aka Void->Void). Strictly speaking, printThat has type (() -> ()) -> () (aka (Void->Void)->Void "Void function" doesn't has a lot of sense as "Int function" etc ... Every function in Swift has a type, consisting of the function’s parameter types and return type.

Comment: one more 'comment', just for better understanding Swift build-in print has type (Array<protocol<>>, String, String) -> () See the first parameter! Array<protocol<>>, it is nice, isn't it?